# How to center text and image on one line inside a %width div?

Tags: html, css, centering

I am really struggling with this and I have no idea why. I want to have text and an image on 1 line and centered inside a 100% width div. Here's a jsfiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/JnbeJ/

Comment: float left *immediately* disqualifies you from using text-align center.  floating an element makes the element render outside the document flow

Comment: @JonathanRomer no.  see skips answer below

Comment: these statements are incorrect. you can still use float and text-align based on how the OP set up his code. see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

floated elements automatically become block-level. It's impossible to center them via `text-align: center`. The only way for you to do is to make them inline-block like so: `display: inline-block`. I added `vertical-align: top;` for the `h` to be at the top. The working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/JnbeJ/4/

Comment: the wrapper div allows him to center the content using text-align. but the wrapper div also needs a width or be made inline-block.

Comment: @Matt K, it doesn't really matter where to put `text-align: center;`. It is inherited. As you can see from my jsfiddle I center `h1` and `img` and not their wrapper.

Comment: @skip405, then why have a wrapper? putting a width on the wrapper and centering it is a better choice because `inline-block` is not supported/buggy in previous versions of IE. take a look at your example in IE5/6/7 and you will see. also no need to vertically align the textual content.

Comment: @Matt K, sorry but I am not going to argue with your) Read my comment and compare the two fiddles that I made and decide for yourself where the CONTENT is centered and where the WRAPPER is centered. To tell you the truth I've never done the centering of a wrapper in this way, I simply made it for you to demonstrate that floated elements will not be centered even within a centered div.

Comment: @skip405, "floated elements will not be centered even within a centered div" [you're just doing it wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/3TuSh/1/).

Comment: @Matt K, in your latest fiddle you have your TEXT aligned center because the `text-align` property inherits. That doesn't center the whole `h1` element. The easy way to check WHAT is REALLY centered is to set a wider width (http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/JnbeJ/8/). If you really think that FLOATS are centered via `text-align` not the `inline-block` WRAPPER of yours, I cannot help you)

Comment: @skip405, I have no idea why you're so confused and misinterpreting the line of questioning to suit your answers, but you must be right because of all the CAPS.

Comment: @Matt K, pity that you pay attention to how something is written and not to what is written. Please read the question once again where it is explicitly stated to center the `img` & `h1` in a 100% div. My solution can do that whereas yours - not. Your way centers only the inner wrapper which looses 100% width by the way) and not the `img` and `h1` - which is not answering this question or to be more exact it is an answer to another question ('How do we center a div?' probably). Animated example of centering the floats vs centering the inline-block can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/jwv96/2/

Comment: @skip405, the outer div is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Your image and text can't float left and be centred at the same time...

Comment: they can since he's contained them in a wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

You have a div that is 100% width (btw/ divs are 100% to begin with), and trying to center a div inside it that is also 100% width. You can either put a width on the inner div, or make it `inline-block`.

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3TuSh/)

Comment: In your case the `div` which you will make inline-block will be centered, whereas the `h1` and `img` will NOT be centered even within that div via `text-align: center`. See this fiddle where the div with the green background is centered and its contents isn't. http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/JnbeJ/8/

Comment: @skip405, it's not centered because you un-centered it... in my example the h1 has a fluid width, you gave it a specific width and didn't center it. not sure what you're trying to argue here.

Comment: please, show me the exact line in my css that "un-centers" the content and the exact line where h1 is given specific width.

Comment: @skip405, you gave it's parent a specific width, thereby increasing the width that the h1 has to expand to.

Comment: are you sure that the `h1` tag expanded its width? Give it a background and see for yourself that the width is not expanded at all. There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/JnbeJ/32/

Comment: @skip405, you're still using your own code to illustrate my point. it's like saying- your drawing looks like shit even though you're looking at a completely different drawing.

Comment: this code is different from yours only in line where I add a width. Hope you agree that `width` of a parent doesn't influence the centering of its children) If so pay attention to the last fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jwv96/2/) Before the animation both variants (mine is at the top; yours at the bottom (I didn't change a single line, didn't add anything new, it's your variant) look visually almost the same (they seem centered)... what YOU do here is this: "See? they are in the center - so they are centered" but I make the block a bit wider to check if they really are. Yours aren't.

Comment: misinterpret my explanation > write your own code based off it > it doesn't work as expected > so mine must not be right as well... good job.

Comment: explain your point once again > make a couple of fiddles that prove your point > make it work like needed > get upvoted. Up to you, buddy ;) The only thing that you write is that I misinterpret you. Forgive me but that's just empty words

Comment: Do you consider your words (`You can either put a width on the inner div, or make it inline-block`) a correct answer to the question? Or a well-explained one? Especially after I did the first part of it (setting the width of the wrapper) - which aroused your accuses of me un-centering the content and ruining your code... I have got only one question for you, Matt K, before the moderators can freely delete this conversation (and I hope you will answer): "Can floated elements be centered via `text-align` property set on their parent?" Y/N

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrapper with class name "centered" so instead of making both elements (display: inline-block;), just add this to style your wrapper:

```
.centered {display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto;}
```

You also have an additional (text-align: center;) in your containers css that does not need to be there.

Comment: You actually don't need the margin either, my bad. just simply .centered {display: inline-block;} will do the trick.